# pyinstaller move .exe file to Desktop

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I made GUI application with PyQt and wrapped it up with pyinstaller.
As you know, make it for onefile (sole exe file) is quite slow.

So, what I want to do is wrap it by using pyinstaller but not in onefile, but i still don't want to execute the exe file in the folder. I want to move the exe file to desktop directory so I can use it like onefile. I tried it but it says there is no .dll on desktop directory.

I assume that there is quite simple solution.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why not just keep the file in the folder and create a shortcut on the desktop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep the file in the folder and create a shortcut on the desktop instead. You can have also shortcuts in the Start menu for example or pin the exe (create shortcut) in TaskBar. If you are going to distribute it a simple installer can automate the creation of the said shortcuts.

Comment: great! I never thought about shortcuts!

Comment: Just one more question. I want to distribute application by making exe installation file that installs files(dll, exe) on some directory and make shortcut on desktop directory. How this can be done?

Comment: you should post this as separate question, but before do so - do your research because most probably it will be closed as duplicate. Check for example installcreator or nsis

Comment: also inno setup, but there are also others